# .Net Disable a form or disable mouse click until it is completely loaded

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, mouse, disable

I know this has been asked but I am still confused as how to implement it.

The user selects an option by double-clicking on a grid or by pressing an Accept button.  Inevitably, they triple-click or otherwise click on the screen while the new form is loading. this either selects a line on the grid in the new form or presses a button even though the new form is not visible.

I have tried to disable the new form while it is loading - `Form.Disable` and enable it after Shown or even after some other code has run.  However, it seems that the errant mouse clicks are still registered and are performed.

I would think this would be a very common issue and that there would be an easy solution.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What Forms we are talking about here? WebForms, WinForms, something else?

Comment: If your loading is taking that long to do what it needs to do that users are hammering the mouse, maybe it's worth putting some sort of loading animation in, tends to keep users happy watching little spinny things

Comment: Sorry - It's a VB.NET windows forms project.  It doesn't take that long to load, but it happens because people just click the mouse too many times.  I would like to block input after their mouse clicks and then enable it after the screen loads if possible.